# Python - How to display two counters in for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, counter

Im trying to achieve next effect:

I have two counters, one should be "Current" counter that should count from 1 to 123, while there should be also counter named "Total" on bottom of console that should display total count for example 234.

**This is my code:**

```
import sys
import time

n = 0
for _ in range(0, 5):
    i = 1
    for _ in range(0, 123):
        sys.stdout.write("\r    " + "Current: %d" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i = i + 1
        n = n + 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

    print('')
    sys.stdout.write("\rTotal: %d" % n)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

It is almost what i want, except that "Total" line is overwritten every time when inner for loop is performed. SO there should be always displayed only one "Total" line with total number of loops.

Is this possible to do in Python and how?

Comment: This sounds like you're building a more complex console GUI than simple io. Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html?

Comment: Putting everything in one line would be a lot easier...

Comment: @Joost No, but i will check it out.

Comment: @swenzel thats not what i want

Comment: @RhymeGuy got that. I just wanted to point out that sometimes the alternative, despite being less attractive, might be worth considering if it saves you a lot of time and a headache ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after playing with curses as suggested by @Joost

**Final code:**

```
import time
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

n = 0
b = 0
for _ in range(0, 5):
    i = 1
    for _ in range(0, 123):
        stdscr.addstr(b, 0, "Current: %d" % i)
        i = i + 1
        n = n + 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
        stdscr.addstr(b+1, 0, "Total: %d" % n)
        stdscr.refresh()
    b = b + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want two lines, you can make use of the `CPL` (Cursor Previous Line) [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move the cursor to the beginning of the previous line.

```
import sys
import time
import colorama

print('')
total = 0
for _ in range(0, 5):
    current = 1
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    for _ in range(0, 123):
        sys.stdout.write("\rCurrent: %03d" % current)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        current += 1
        total += 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

    sys.stdout.write("\nTotal: %d" % total)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Note that on Windows you have to import the [`colorama` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) first.

Comment: This works same as my example, and thats not what i want :)

Comment: @RhymeGuy Are you saying that the `Total` line gets overwritten? Works fine for me. Are you using the `colorama` module?

Comment: Yes, im using colorama module. Total is line gets overwritten.

Comment: @RhymeGuy What OS/Terminal are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 with PyCharm console

Comment: @RhymeGuy Could you try the standard `cmd` terminal?

Comment: Same, Total gets overwritten by Current on every iteration. As in my example, i see it shortly for 0,5s, then it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

The console writing is only happening on a single line and hence it will clear the 'total'.

One way is to always print the 'Total' along with the 'Current' on the next line.

```
for _ in range(0, 123):
    i = i + 1
    sys.stdout.write("\r    " + "Current: %d" % i)
    n = n + 1
    sys.stdout.write("\rTotal: %d" % n)

    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Or, have a separate rendering loop (on another thread) which prints these global variables (current and total) continuously. It will have its own refresh rate.

Comment: Thats not what im trying to achieve.